# Div adjust after Absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with adjusting my footer after my absolute `<div>`.
This is the scenario:

I have a `<div>` which contains a background image - this `<div>` is Absolute
I have all my content in another `<div>` which is positioned upon the image itself
My footer should "float" underneath the image, but this doesn't happen.

**[A live preview](http://danne-bro.com.web122.curanetserver.dk/how.aspx)**

As you can see, the footer is ON the image, it should be underneath it, no matter what height the image has.

My markup would be something like this:

```
<div id="banner"><img src="#" /> Position Absolute</div>
<div id="container">
   Content goes in here
</div>
<div id="footer">
   This footer should always be under the banner
</div>
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this method

```
    <div id="banner">Position Absolute</div>
          <div id="container">
                   Content goes in here
          </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
          <div id="footer">
                   This footer should always be under the banner
          </div>


    .clear{ clear:both}
      #footer{ position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

Note: i have updated the answer which will keep the footer at the bottom.

Comment: Yes I tried that. It still makes the footer div position itself to the contents height, not the banner image

Comment: This does make the footer go below the image, but now it's at the very bottom :) It's supposed to be just underneath the image. It's a really hard task to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on having an absolute DIV and setting its position for the background.  It would be better to have this as a relative div and set the background image.  You can use CSS background-position and margin: 0 auto to float it center.  That way the footer div will always sit underneath.

Relative divs do not take absolute div positioning into account.

Comment: Doing this seems to push the content underneath the banner. I have set the Banners Div to relative and background-position to top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the issue...but I guess you looking for "sticky footer".

The problem is your content div. 
You should make your content div relative or float, and then you can add sticky footer:

```
<div id="footer">Footer</div>

#footer{position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;....}
```

Comment: my issue is that I can't get the footer to stay right underneath the image (17px under it or so). Having a sticky footer in the very bottom is not exactly what is supposed to happen. The footer should be just under the background image/banner, no matter it's size.